# How to pass the in-place edited content back to the previous tableview controller (update the model)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table views, one called mainTableViewController (mtvc), the other called detailTableViewController (dtvc). It's very typical click the accessory button on the main tableview cell bring you to the detail tableview kinda thing.

In the prepareForSegue method, the data passed from the main tableview to detail tableview is a NSMutableArray called item.

And this is how I got it displayed: cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.item[indexPath.row];

The cool thing is I managed to do in-place editing on the detail table view cell (overwrote the NSTableViewCell, added a UITextField as subview to each cell).

everything works, the last thing I spent whole day cannot figure out is how do I update the NSMutableArray item after in-place editing taken place, the ultimate goal is in-place editing, and the main tableview data shall reflect the change.

I tried to use delegation and protocol but it does not work (the in-place edited content didn't got passed back, part of the reason is I don't know how to capture the edited content, it's not like it's a text field with a name, I can't just do updatedContent = self.myTextField.text to grab the change)

I'm running out of ideas, any help would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Here's the prepareForSegue in the main tableview controller

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toInventoryDetail"]) {

            NSMutableArray *selectedItem = nil;

            if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
                selectedItem = _searchResults[[sender row]];
            } else {
                selectedItem = _appDelegate.items[[sender row]];
            }

            UPFInventoryDetailTableViewController *idtvc = segue.destinationViewController;
            idtvc.item = selectedItem;
        }
    }
```

and here's the cellForRowAtIndex at the detail tableview controller

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UPFEditableUITableViewCell *cell = [[UPFEditableUITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = _appDelegate.title[indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = self.item[indexPath.row];

        [cell showEditingField:YES];

        return cell;
    }
```

I wrote the delegation but delete them after cause they didn't work.

I had an idea, still using delegation and protocol obviously: when the 'done' button in the detail tableview hit, I go grab all the row contents and build a new array, using delegation to pass this new array back to the main tableview controller, add this new array into the model meanwhile delete the old one. The tricky thing is still HOW CAN I GRAB ALL THE CONTENTS in the detail tableview?

update:
Haha! I think solved half of the puzzle !

here's the solution for the detail tableview controller

```
    - (IBAction)doneUpdate:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
        [self.delegate addItem:[self newItem]];
    }

    - (NSMutableArray *)saveItem
    {
        NSMutableArray *newItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *indexPathes = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPathes) {
                UPFEditableUITableViewCell *cell = (UPFEditableUITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [newItem addObject:cell.editField.text];
        }
        return newItem;
    }
```

and here's the main tableview controller

```
    - (void)addItem:(NSArray *)item
    {
        //take the updated item then insert the items array as new item
        [_appDelegate.items addObject:item];
        //remove the selected item (the one being updated) from the items array
        [_appDelegate.items removeObject:_appDelegate.selectedItem];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: I had an idea, still using delegation and protocol obviously: when the 'done' button in the detail tableview hit, I go grab all the row contents and build a new array, using delegation to pass this new array back to the main tableview controller, add this new array into the model meanwhile delete the old one. The tricky thing is still HOW CAN I GRAB ALL THE CONTENTS in the detail tableview?

Comment: Show the code for your editing and your delegate implementation so far

Comment: Do you need to update "item"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you creating a cell** - **give tags to your** `UITextFields`
You can collect data entered by its delegate methods - you can either make `NSDictionary`/ key value pairs or you can add it to `NSArray`.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

       if(textField.tag == 11) {

          // you can add it to your desired array/dictionary
       }  

}

OR

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

 if(textField.tag == 11) {

          // you can add it to your desired array/dictionary
       }  
}
```

You can use `Delegation/Protocol` or store this values in `NSUserDefault` and get it back on mainViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate data model class(classes) for your `selectedItem`? That would be the appropriate way to persist data between the two TableViewControllers. It can be Core Data or simply a NSMutableArray that lives in memory. The DetailViewController updates the `item` and saves the changes, then the mainTableViewController reloads the TableView (or even just the data backing the previously edited cell.
Perhaps even consider the Model-View-Controller-Store [pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184396/mvcs-model-view-controller-store) promoted by [BigNerdRanch](http://bignerdranch.com).

Comment: yes, race_carr, I'm currently store the data in a NSMutableArray in the memory. The thing I can't figure out is how to capture those in-place edited content in the detail tableview controller, as I said, the textfields are the subview of the tableview cell, they don't come with a name (like tableviewcell1_textField) so that I can grab the text in them (like tabviewcell1_textField.text)

Comment: haha, I think I might know where to start solving this problem, I can get to those contents by cell.editField.text, then let me figure out of the rest